# Database exception handling in ASP.NET MVC 5 (SQL Server)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to save exceptions like my SQL Server code throws in a `LOG` table in my database.

What exceptions action is best for it in ASP.NET MVC 5?

1. `try...catch`
2. Overriding `OnException` method
3. Using the `[HandleError]` attribute on actions and controllers
4. Setting a global exception handling filter
5. Handling `Application_Error` event

Can I use `[HandleError]`?

Comment: You really need to use every technique you can, depending on where the error occurs it can slip through the various mechanisms pretty easy. There is no one stop shop for handling errors in MVC. A combo of manual logging handling, error filters, client side error handling and even global error handling is required if you really want to catch everything to log.

Comment: I would use #1 where ever you open a db connection. However, #5 will do a catch all if any exceptions slip through. Although they may not necessarily be SQL exceptions.

Comment: IMHO, Action Filters are the best practice of that.  Also take a look, Interceptors for aspect oriented programming.

Comment: look into elmah (https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/) to start.  This will give you out of the box handling of all unhandled errors in your application.  That at least gives you the ability to log all exception.  Then you can add specific try/catches if you can recover from the error.